# how to make an image disappear when another image touches it? html/Js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok so i have a program that draws 3 ghosts with random positions and draws a bag "sac.gif" that you can move around using the arrow keys on your keyboard on a 400 by 400 canvas. I'm trying to make it so that whenever the user moves the bag image over the ghost image, the one of three ghost images disappear while the other two stay in their positions and await until the bag image hovers over them and makes them disappear aswell. That is where the problem is... i'm not too sure how i would be able to make a function that checks if the bag and the ghost image are touching and removing the ghost image if it is.
all help is appreciated.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jeu.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
    style="border-color: 'black'; border-width: 3px; border-style: solid">
      </canvas>
      <br>
        <button type="button"onclick="reset()"><img src="start.jpg"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">


window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);

  };
})();

window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var contexte = canvas.getContext("2d");

var T_fleche_gauche = 37;
var T_fleche_droite = 39;
var T_fleche_haut = 38;
var T_fleche_bas = 40;

var player = {
    img: new Image();
  };
var x = 100;
  var y = 100;"
  var  w = 64;
  var  h = 64;
  var dx = 0;
  var dy = 0;

  player.img.src = "sac.gif"

  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  toucheCourante = e.keyCode;

  if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_gauche) {
   dx = -1;
   dy = 0;
}
  if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_droite) {
       dx = 1;
       dy = 0;
    }
    if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_haut) {
       dy = -1;
       dx = 0;
    }
    if (toucheCourante == T_fleche_bas) {
       dy = 1;
      dx = 0;
    }
  }

function dessiner(x, y) {
      var random = function() {
      return {
        x: w + (Math.random() * (400 - (2*w))),
        y: h + (Math.random() * (400 - (2*h)))
      }
    };
  var points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      points.push( random() );
    }
    return points;
  };
var ghost = {
    img: new Image(),
    };
ghost.img.src = "ghost.png";

function affiche(x,y) {
   for (var u of ghost.list) {
     contexte.drawImage(ghost.img, u.x, u.y, 50, 60);
   }
 }

  ghost.list  = dessiner(3, ghost);



    function draw() {
    contexte.save();
    contexte.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    contexte.translate(10+2*x,10+2*y);
    contexte.drawImage(player.img, x,y,70,90);
    contexte.restore();

    x = x+dx;
    y = y+dy;

    if (x > 125) x = -25;
    if (x < -25) x = 125;
    if (y > 125) y = -25;
    if (y < -25) y = 125;

    affiche();

    window.requestAnimFrame(function() {draw(dx,dy)});
  };

  draw(1,0);

};

function reset(){
location.reload()
}
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to implement a function to determine whether two objects collide, providing their `x` and `y` coordinates and their `width` and `height`.
So something like this: `function collide(o1, o2) {...} // returns true if they are colliding, false otherwise`. To write this function, you may find this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Then, you need to call it in your `update()` function for each objects which collision is supposed to do something (not your ghosts between each other I suspect). Each time your update the state of the game (objects positions, etc) and redraw, you need to check if objects are colliding. 
Then, you need to do something if a collision if detected: life drop, explosion, gameover...

I didn't manage to make your jsfiddle work, so I used the one I made last time and updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/t0c3sh8f/36/

**EDIT**: I forgot to make the ghosts disappear. To make everything easier, I created `Bag` and `Ghost` objects: https://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/t0c3sh8f/56/